# Join hive tables which are being populated in real time

Tags: join, optimization, hive

I have two tables in hive which are being populated in real time from a set of files. There is a request_time and trx_id columns in both tables where trx_id is the joining key.

I want to join them and put the result in another table (in real time or near-real time). The problem is how do I ensure that I have not missed any records. e.g. what if a trx_id had arrived in one table and not the other?

My initial solution is to keep a track of the trx_id in another table for a particular time period which have been processed and when joining the two tables exclude the records which exist in this table. However it would be a bit time consuming process. Any suggestions?

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN will join records by trx_id value which is present in at least one table. If it is absent in another table the relevant fields values will be NULL.

Comment: The transactions IDs should be present in both tables, however, it may happen that the record arrives late in one of the table. The mapping is always a one to one with an inner join.

Comment: I'd recommend you to insert into a question text (edit): DDL of all 3 tables, inserting sample data script, and desured result on that data. The best way - additionally create a fiddle and post a link to it.

Comment: *it may happen that the record arrives late in one of the table.* It doesn't matter. *The problem is how do I ensure that I have not missed any records.* FULL JOIN + test that the fields from any table is not NULL. Additionally - "put the result in another table" is INSERT, "ensure that I have not missed any records" is SELECT, so 2 separate queries needed... and the state of the tables can change between queries.